# Formatting String With LEading Zero's

Tags: c#, formatting

I am trying to convert an object (coming from a SQL server), into a integer so I can format the number to have the correct amount of zero's in front of it.

For example:

If I were to have **25.6**, I would need it to be **0025.6**.

Now I have looked online on  how to do this, but the methods that I have seen people post are not working for me. I am not entirely sure why. I am trying to format `GlobalVariables.grossweightafter`. I read the value `GlobalVariables.grossweight` from the SQL server, but then when I `TryParse` it, it loses its value. The code I have is below:

```
            while (TransferRecord.Read())
            {
                //Pulling data from the SQL server. getting data for every line of code as specified.
                GlobalVariables.baledate = TransferRecord["keyprinter_datetime"];
                GlobalVariables.baleline = TransferRecord["pulp_line_id"];
                GlobalVariables.baleid = TransferRecord["bale_id"];
                GlobalVariables.grossweight = TransferRecord["bale_gross_weight"];
                GlobalVariables.grossweightflag = TransferRecord["gross_value_flag"];
                GlobalVariables.baleairdrypercent = TransferRecord["bale_airdry_pct"];
                GlobalVariables.airdryflag = TransferRecord["airdry_value_flag"];

                //Converting the date, and the baleid to fit in the string.
                DateTime.TryParse(GlobalVariables.baledate.ToString(), out GlobalVariables.baledateafter);
                int.TryParse(GlobalVariables.baleid.ToString(), out GlobalVariables.baleidafter);

                int.TryParse(GlobalVariables.grossweight.ToString(), out GlobalVariables.grossweightafter);
                GlobalVariables.grossweightafter.ToString("0000.0");
                //Calling the WriteData method.
                WriteData();
            }
```

So I was wondering if anyone can catch what I am doing wrong, or they can help me out on the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Using the return value of ToString() is recommended.  Just like you should never ignore the return value of TryParse().

Comment: You are saying I should use `GlobalVariables.grossweightafter.ToString()`?

Comment: Expanding slightly on what @HansPassant said: when you use `TryParse()`, you should check the return value and branch based on whether the value was parseable.  E.g., set the value to "Unrecognized" if the value could not be parsed to an integer.  If you want to bull on through without checking, just use `string myVar = Int32.Parse(rawValue)`.  Finally... why are you parsing to `int` if the value is expected to have a decimal?

Comment: I didn't think of the int, I changed it to a double, and did what ps2goat had suggested. I have found the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use `double.TryParse()` method instead of `int.TryParse()`, because int does not have fractional part?

Also, you need to store `ToString()` result to a string variable. Your code should be like this:

```
GlobalVariables.grossweightafterstring = GlobalVariables.grossweightafter.ToString("0000.0");
```

Answer (score 2):

What @Hans Passant was saying is that you need to assign the value returned from .ToString.  That line should be:

```
GlobalVariables.grossweightafter = GlobalVariables.grossweightafter.ToString("0000.0");
```

Answer (score 2):

The last lines should be

```
if(int.TryParse(GlobalVariables.grossweight.ToString(), out GlobalVariables.grossweightafter))
{
    string grossWeightAfter = GlobalVariables.grossweightafter.ToString("0000.0");
    //you need to save the string returned from the ToString-method somewhere or it will be lost.
    ///Alternatively, if GlobalVariables can contain strings aswell:
    GlobalVariables.grossweightafter = GlobalVariables.grossweightafter.ToString("0000.0");
}
else
{
    //React on value not being an int
}
```